# Will I get a new populist badge for a new answer if the answer I got for the first one became accepted?

Tags: support, answers, badges, accepted-answer

Let's assume this scenario:

1. I get the populist badge for a specific answer (as it outscores the accepted answer by the required margin)
2. The asker later changes the accepted mark to my answer, so it becomes accepted. I still retain the badge however as they don't get removed.
3. On a completely different question I also get an answer that outscores the accepted one by the required margin

Now if (2) would happen after (3) then I think I'll be having two populist badges in the end.

But in the described case will I get two in the end or am I only keeping one?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can get that badge multiple times regardless. - confirmed. You get it every time you meet the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badges don't operate on a "you should have this number of this badge type" system anymore. They *used to* long ago, but haven't for quite some time.

They are awarded per-post. That means if you are eligible for a badge on that particular post, and the badge can be awarded multiple times, and you don't have it on that post yet, you will receive it for that post regardless of how it's been awarded on past posts.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Why not?

The Populist badge can be awarded multiple times, with the only restriction that it can't be awarded more than once **for the same answer**.

We generally don't revoke badges, nor do we refuse to award more badges if previous badges are awarded for posts that no longer meets the criteria. You can still earn further Nice Answer badges even if all your previous answers dropped down to below +10.

Comment: Tumbleweed is a bad example - that badge is only awarded once. ;)

Comment: @animuson My bad :)

Comment: It doesn't. When the badge was originally introduced, we still had a system where it counted how many of that badge type you should have. And since it's *very* easy to stop qualifying for Tumbleweed after earning the badge, it was hard to earn multiples anyways because as you'd add one to the count, you'd lose one from the count elsewhere. So it was just awarded once and done. We could probably change that now, but I don't see much reason to.